# Sending mail in a loop

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I have a PHP script which receives data (from UDP port) parses it and supposed to send mail based on some parameters.

The script runs in endless loop and what changes is only mail body

I created all required variables, and sent first mail before entering the loop and it works fine, but once in loop I get error as below.
Do I need to close the connection to the mail server? or perform some kind of action before sending again?

The following From address failed: roni@yozma.net
Mailer Error: The following From address failed: roni@yozma.net

SMTP server error: 4.4.2 Timeout - closing connection. o10sm17869807wiz.5 - gsmtp

Comment: We're supposed to figure out what's wrong without seeing any code? OK, the problem is on line 53.

Comment: Endless loop? Are you spamming?

Comment: a firewall maybe blocking spammy mail server connections

Comment: The code is attached, I am new to PHP <?php

https://www.dropbox.com/s/25bsxvnwsuecn0b/cli1.php

Comment: Is your OS unix/linux/bsd or MS Windows? Which php functiom/library do you use to send emails?